# WinSCP read from a remote located script file

Tags: winscp

Can WinSCP read from a remote located script file?

Example:

```
C:\programs\winscp574\WinSCP.com /script=http://example.com/winscpftptest.txt

(or C:\programs\winscp574\WinSCP.com /script:http://example.com/winscpftptest.txt)
```

but the WinSCP response is

> Cannot open file "C:\ftptest\http:\example.com\winscpftptest.txt"

expecting a local script file

Does WinSCP support this functionality?

If so, is it another syntax of the `/script` switch, another command or another way of scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, WinSCP does not support that.

You have to download the script to a local file.

---

You can use the the following PowerShell script:

```sh
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.example.com/winscpftptest.txt -OutFile winscpftptest.txt
C:\programs\winscp574\WinSCP.com /script=winscpftptest.txt
```

---

Or you can use for example the [wget for Windows](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) from a batch file.